# PowerApps Delegation

Tags: powerapps, delegation

i am trying to get past the 500 record delegation but cant do so. I prefer to fix the delegation than to set the record in advanced setting to 2000, i will have so many more records in the future.

my other question is, how would i get the current code to display record from now to the last 10 days as an example

this is my code

```
Sort(
Search(
Filter(
    'My Data Source',
    IsBlank(ChamberFilter.SelectedItems.Value) || IsEmpty(ChamberFilter.SelectedItems) || Chamber.Value= ChamberFilter.Selected.Value,
    IsBlank(ReceiptCHKFilter.SelectedItems.Value) || IsEmpty(ReceiptCHKFilter.SelectedItems) || Un_x002f_Receipted = ReceiptCHKFilter.Selected.Value,
    IsBlank(SiteFilter.SelectedItems.Value) || IsEmpty(SiteFilter.SelectedItems) || Site.Value = SiteFilter.Selected.Value,
    IsBlank(DateFilter.SelectedDate) || IsEmpty(DateFilter.SelectedDate) || field_6 = DateFilter.SelectedDate

),
TextSearchBookingRefs.Text,
"Ref_x0020_Lookup"),
ID,Descending)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original issue was getting past the 500 records restriction, which is the default setting.  As i do not have admin access i could not change the limit to 2000.

As per my question, the next option was to set a delegation filter, however my issue here was that the columns i was looking up to were calculated columns.

Delegation only seem to work with inputted columns not calculated columns off a SharePoint worklist.

My workaround was to create input columns on the app.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.matthewdevaney.com/create-power-apps-collections-over-2000-rows-with-these-4-tricks/) is a good article on moving past the 2000 limit.

As for the second question, Instead of ID you can sort it by `CreatedDate` and `DateAdd` function:

```
Filter(collection, CreatedDate>DateAdd(Today(), -10, Days))
```